# Common Lisp EVAL Function Quotations

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, eval

My question is rather simple (perhaps misleadingly so).

In Common Lisp, when I run the following command, I get the corresponding results:

```
(eval '''boo) => 'boo
```

If, on the other hand, I run the following command I get something slightly different.

```
(eval (eval '''boo)) => boo
```

My question is this: if the first command's `eval` "shaves off" two quotation marks from the variable-symbol and leaves it with one mark at the output, how is it possible that the two nested `eval` functions take off a total of three quotation marks?

This is particularly confusing because the following results in an error:

```
(eval 'boing) => ERROR. BOING is unbound.
```

Answer (score 9):

`'boo` is an abbreviation for `(quote boo)`. In code, `quote` is a special form that evaluates to whatever it's argument it and nothing more. Thus `boo`. When this value is passed around it's data and no longer code but in order to create the symbol `foo` you need `quote`.

`'''boo` is an abbreviation for `(quote (quote (quote boo)))`. When evaluating it it does exactly as before and it becomes `(quote (quote boo))`, a list with two elements where the second element is a list of two elements.

Since `eval` is a function it first evaluates the argument, then it evaluates the result as the function is supposed to do. Thus `(quote (quote foo))` becomes `(quote foo)` after the first evaluation and `eval` takes off the second leaving the symbol `foo`.

If `eval` gets a symbol `foo` it means it's supposed to get the value bound by the variable `foo` in the global namespace. Thus:

```
(defparameter *test* 5)
(eval '*test*)
; ==> 5
```

Since the argument is `(quote *test*)` which after evaluation becomes `*test*`. `eval` sees the symbol and fetches the value, `5`, which is the result. If `*test*` is not bound you get the error you got.

```
(defparameter *test-symbol* '*test)
(eval *test-symbol*)
```

Same here. Since it's a function `*test-symbol*` is evaluated to the symbol `*test*`, this is what `eval` sees and it fetches the value `5`.

```
(defparameter *result* (eval '''foo))
*result*
; ==> (quote foo) but often the REPL shows 'foo
(consp *result*)
; ==> t
(length *result*)
; ==> 2
(car *result*)
; ==> quote
(cadr *result*)
; ==> foo
```

Sometimes I see beginners do something like `'('(a) '(b))`. This is a mistake as when evaluated you end up with the list `((quote (a)) (quote (b)))` as the data and it is seldom the intention. When using a function like `list` the arguments gets evaluated and you need to quote appropriately:

```
(list '(a) *result* '(b))
; ==> ((a) (quote foo) (b))
```

Answer (score 5):

`eval` is a function. Its argument is evaluated before `eval` is applied to it. That's why it appears that `eval` "shaves off" two quotation marks. One is removed by the implicit evaluation of function application, the other by the `eval` application itself.

But when you evoke `(eval (eval '''boo))` the outer `eval` is applied to the value `'boo` that is returned from the inner `eval`. The equivalent is `(eval ''boo)`.

When you try `(eval 'boing)` the argument is evaluated before `eval` is applied to it, so `eval` tries to evaluate `boing` and goes wrong.

Contrast this with a macro version of `eval` that doesn't evaluate its argument before applying `eval`...

```
? (defmacro meval (form) `(eval ',form))           
MEVAL
? (meval 'foo)
FOO
? (meval '''foo)
''FOO
```

Answer (score 5):

**First question:**

```
Evaluating (eval '''boo)

   Evaluating '''boo
   Result: ''boo

   Calling Function EVAL with ''boo
   Function EVAL returns 'boo

Result: 'boo
```

**Second question:**

```
Evaluating (eval (eval '''boo))

    Evaluating (eval '''boo)

       Evaluating '''boo
       Result: ''boo

       Calling EVAL with ''boo
       Function EVAL returns 'boo

    Calling Function EVAL with 'boo
    Function EVAL returns boo

Result: boo
```